# Cannot add new row in DataGrid through Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TotalMatch" ItemsSource="{Binding MatchStat}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="In corso" Binding="{Binding Path = PlayingMatch}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

what I what to do is create a count of items so the result should be:

```
| In corso |
     5
```

I set the Binding to PlayingMatch, for this in the ViewModel class I defined this:

```
public Models.MatchStat MatchStat = new Models.MatchStat();
```

so in the Model I've this definition:

```
public class MatchStat : ViewModel
{
    private static int _playingMatch    = 0;
    public int PlayingMatch
    {
        get { return _playingMatch; }
        set { SetField(ref _playingMatch, value); }
    }
}
```

when I add a new value as count I did this:

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.MatchStat.PlayingMatch += 1;
```

but no row is displayed under "in corso" cell, why?

Answer (score 1):

The DataGrid.Itemssource must be assigned with an IEnumerable (collection, array or list) object.
Use ObservableCollection which implements IEnumerable, and also keeps your Window updated if it changes in code-behind (item added or removed from the collection).

Your declaration in the ViewModel class should be like:

```
public ObservableCollection<Models.MatchStat> MatchStats = new ObservableCollection<Models.MatchStat>();
```

Now, you need to create a MatchStat object and add it to the collection you initialize before.

```
Models.MatchStat matchStat1 = new Models.MatchStat();
matchStat1.PlayingMatch += 1;

MatchStats.Add(matchStat1);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your ItemsSource should be a collection of MatchStat.
2. Have you assigned vm as the Window's DataContext?

Comment: 1. I doesn't want any collection, just a single value. 2. yes

Comment: Well, ItemsSource must get an IEnumerable object. Put your object in an array or in ObservableCollection

Comment: with this I'll take other column with properties name